# PHP: tokenizing, using a regular Expression (mostly there)

Tags: php, regex, tokenize

I want to tokenize formatting strings (very roughly like printf) and I think I am only missing a small bit:

- %[number][one letter ctYymd] shall become a token²
- $1...$10 shall become a token
- all else (normal text) becomes a token.

I got quite far in [the regExp simulator](https://regex101.com/r/tR7zE5/10). This looks like it should do:

²update: now using # instead of %. (Less troubles with windows command line parameters)

[image]

It's not scary, if you focus on the three parts, connected by pipes (as either-or), so basically it's just three matches. Since I want to match from start to end, I wrapped things in `/^...%/` and surrounded by a non-matching group `(?:...` that may repeat 1 or more times:

```
$exp = '/^(?:(%\\d*[ctYymd]+)|([^$%]+)|(\\$\\d))+$/';
```

Still my source doesn't deliver:

```
$exp = '/^(?:(%\\d*[ctYymd]+)|([^$%]+)|(\\$\\d))+$/';
echo "expression: $exp \n";

$tests = [
        '###%04d_Ball0n%02d$1',
        '%03d_Ball0n%02x$1%03d_Ball0n%02d$1',
        '%3d_Ball0n%02d',
    ];

foreach ( $tests as $test )
{
    echo "teststring: $test\n";
    if( preg_match( $exp, $test, $tokens) )
    {
        array_shift($tokens);
        foreach ( $tokens as $token )
            echo "\t\t'$token'\n";
    }
    else
        echo "not valid.";
} // foreach
```

I get results but: Matches are out of order. The first %[number][letter] never matches, therefore others match double:

```
expression: /^((%\d*[ctYymd]+)|([^$%]+)|(\$\d))+$/ 
teststring: ###%04d_Ball0n%02d$1
        '$1'
        '%02d'
        '_Ball0n'
        '$1'
teststring: %03d_Ball0n%02x$1%03d_Ball0n%02d$1
not valid.teststring: %3d_Ball0n%02d
        '%02d'
        '%02d'
        '_Ball0n'
teststring: %d_foobardoo
        '_foobardoo'
        '%d'
        '_foobardoo'
teststring: Ball0n%02dHamburg%d
        '%d'
        '%d'
        'Hamburg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution (edited by OP): I use a two slight variations (only regarding ‘wrapping’): first for validation, then for tokenizing, of:

```
#\d*[ctYymd]+|\$\d+|[^#\$]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tR7zE5/12)

**Code:**

```
$core = '#\d*[ctYymd]+|\$\d+|[^#\$]+';
$expValidate = '/^('.$core.')+$/m';
$expTokenize = '/('.$core.')/m';

$tests = [
        '#3d-',
        '#3d-ABC',
        '***#04d_Ball0n#02d$1',
        '#03d_Ball0n#02x$AwrongDollar',
        '#3d_Ball0n#02d',
        'Badstring#02xWrongLetterX'
    ];

foreach ( $tests as $test )
{
    echo "teststring: [$test]\n";

    if( ! preg_match_all( $expValidate, $test) )
    {
        echo "not valid.\n";
        continue;
    }
    if( preg_match_all( $expTokenize, $test, $tokens) ) {
        foreach ( $tokens[0] as $token )
            echo "\t\t'$token'\n";
    }

} // foreach
```

**Output:**

```
teststring: [#3d-]
        '#3d'
        '-'
teststring: [#3d-ABC]
        '#3d'
        '-ABC'
teststring: [***#04d_Ball0n#02d$1]
        '***'
        '#04d'
        '_Ball0n'
        '#02d'
        '$1'
teststring: [#03d_Ball0n#02x$AwrongDollar]
not valid.
teststring: [#3d_Ball0n#02d]
        '#3d'
        '_Ball0n'
        '#02d'
teststring: [Badstring#02xWrongLetterX]
not valid.
```

Comment: Won-der-ful! Thank you so much!
To analyse my mistakes: `preg_match_all` rather than `preg_match`. Because: simply wrong. And saves me from the non-matching outer bracket.

Comment: Only thing I am missing: Doesn't yell at me on errorneous strings, just skips, i.e. `Badstring%02xWrongLetterX`.

Comment: Hmm try this regex [`$exp = '/(%\d*[ctYymd]+|\$\d+|.+?(?=%\d*[ctYymd]|\$\d|$))/m'`](https://regex101.com/r/tR7zE5/12)

Comment: Your lookahead `(?` did not solve it for me. Wrong expression led to a single matching block (which is no sure indication of a wrong format string). Came up with two minor variation, edited your post. (Hope that's ok). (also replaced % for # for unrelated reasons.)